# What is the exterior derivative of a connection form?

Tags: differential-geometry

What is the exterior derivative of a connection form?

Given a principal $G$-bundle $P$ with base space $B$, we assume that $G$ is a Lie group and $P,B$ are smooth manifold. A connection form is a Lie algebra valued 1 form
\begin{equation}
 A=\sum_{i=1}^kA_i\otimes X_i\in\Omega^1(P)\otimes \mathfrak g
\end{equation}
such that

1. $A$ is $G$-invariant with repect to the product action of $G$ on $P$ and $\mathfrak g$
2. $A$ is vertical, i.e. $A(X^\#)=X$ for $X\in\mathfrak g$, where $X^\#$ is the vector field over $P$ induced by $X\in\mathfrak g$

My question is: what is $dA$? It seems that $dA\in\Omega^2(P)\otimes\mathfrak g$ and 
\begin{equation}
 dA(X,Y)\xrightarrow{?}X\cdot A(Y)-Y\cdot A(X)-A([X,Y])
\end{equation}
then what is $X\cdot A(Y)$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can always view a vector field as a derivation of the algebra of smooth functions, this is what it is here. Do you know the relationship the differential and the Lie bracket?

Comment: @A.Rod Do you mean $X\cdot A(Y)$ should be $\mathcal L_X A(Y)$, and here $A(Y)$ is a function $P\to \mathfrak g$? Should it be just $\sum(\mathcal L_X A_i(Y))\otimes X_i$?

Comment: For a function, with value in a "fixed" vector space $V$ (here $V$ is $\mathfrak{g})$, all the notions coincide $L_X(f)=X.f=df.X$ and take value in $V$.
But in my comment I was not talking about the Lie derivative, but the Lie bracket of vector fields. If $\omega$ is a form you have an explicit formula computing $d\omega(X_1,...,X_{n+1})$ in terms of $\omega$, the $X_i$'s and the lie bracket of some of the $X_i$'s (which is easy to show by induction) do you know it?

Comment: @A.Rod Sorry I missed something.

Comment: Yes the edited formula is the one I had in mind. So what is your question exactly? Why is this formula true?

Comment: @A.Rod I prefer the formula to be true because it is true for classical 1-form $\alpha$, and the question is what is $X\cdot A(Y)$ which looks like $X\cdot \alpha(Y)$ but not the same. Now I think it should be $X\cdot A(Y):=A(\mathcal L_X(A(X)^\#))$. So we have $\xi,\zeta\in\mathfrak g$, $dA(\xi^\#,\zeta^\#)=[\xi,\zeta]$.

Comment: Sorry I don't really have time to go into the chat.
But here, $\mathfrak{g}$ is just a trivial bundle, so everything works out the same as it would for the trivial bundle of rank 1. In fact you can write $\mathfrak{g}=\oplus O_X$ and as tensoring commutes with direct sums you're done.

Comment: I come up with this question when reading https://people.math.ethz.ch/~acannas/Papers/lsg.pdf (p.157)    and $dA(\xi^\#,\zeta^\#)=[\xi,\zeta]$ is what I need.